# cycle a tar list and view tar filename that contains a specific file

Tags: unix

In a `filename*.tar.gz` list, I need to view the tar file name where there is the `file1.txt`.
How can I improve this instruction ?

```
for file in filename*.tar.gz; do tar -ztvf "$file" | grep 'file1.txt'  ;done
```

Answer (score 1):

What you have so far will print the entry in a `tar` that matches the pattern "file1.txt", but it will not print the name of the `tar` file itself that contains the entry.

If you want to print the name of the `tar` file that contains `file1.txt`, you can use a conditional statement like this:

```
for file in filename*.tar.gz; do
    if tar ztf "$file" | grep -q file1.txt; then
        echo "$file"
    fi
done
```

The condition here is the exit code of `grep`. If the pattern is found, `grep` exits with zero, which means success, and the `echo "$file"` will be executed.

Also note that I added the `-q` flag to `grep` to make it *quiet*, and do not print the matched line, as it does by default. With this flag, `grep` outputs nothing, and that's fine, we need only the exit code to decide the conditional statement.

A more compact equivalent:

```
for file in filename*.tar.gz; do
    tar ztf "$file" | grep -q file1.txt && echo "$file"
done
```